# Accessing list elements in R

Tags: r

I have a list called "training_data". The "training_data" list contains data read from several files using the following function.

```
training_data <- lapply(files, read.table, header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

I can access the first field of any dataset using the following command:

```
training_data[[1]][1]           # The first field contains the class "pos OR neg"
```

I have to use these datasets (contained within training_data) for binary classification using Support Vector Machines (e1071). But the problem is that certain data sets contains only data for one class i.e either all pos or all neg, which is not acceptable for svm function and I want to exclude those datasets. I have tried the following code but unable to access the class column.

```
training_data<-lapply(training_data, 
                function(data)
                 {
                    if(["the class field is always positive"])
                       ### exclude this dataset from training_data

                 })
```

Update:
How exactly I can access the first column of data passed to function? And How can I exclude those data sets from training_data which consits of only one class in the class column?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `Filter` function was made for. Since you didn't provide replication code, here is a quick example on how to use `Filter`. Suppose you have a large list of vectors, each 2 elements in length:

```
mylist <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) c(runif(1), runif(1)))
```

Now if you want to only retain those vectors in the list where the first element is greater than 0.5, you would do something like this:

```
filtered_list <- Filter(function (x) x[1] > 0.5, mylist)
```

Now, if each element of `mylist` is a `data.frame` and the first column in each `data.frame` is the response vector for the model, as appears to be the case with your data, you can use the `data[,1]` notation mentioned by Justin to filter out all `data.frames` that have only positive or negative values in the first column:

```
filtered_list <- Filter(function (x) { !(all(x[,1] < 0) || all(x[,1] > 0))}, 
                        mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll access the first element the same as you did before. The object `data` is now available to you inside your function and will be the same structure as each data set you've read in to the list.  Thus, `data[1]` or more explicitly `data[,1]` will access them.

I'd suggest you take a look at any of the many excellent guides to R (particularly those listed on [cran.r-project.org](http://cran.r-project.org/)) to get a better idea of how the function is working and how to slice up your data.

If I haven't answered your question, please feel free to ask another or edit this one to include some sample data that replicates the issue you're finding.  As it stands now, this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Thanks alot. How exactly can I exclude those data sets from training_data which contains only one class in the class column?